# Is -w option of sysctl really needed when changing kernel parameters?

Tags: linux-kernel, sysctl

`sysctl` has this [`-w`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/procps-ng/sysctl.8.en#PARAMETERS) switch. Is it really needed? I tried to do:

```
sysctl vm.max_map_count=262144
```

And it seems to have worked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Linux `sysctl`, from `procps-ng`, this was reported [a year ago](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/83), and [the manpage fixed](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/3497521d63d4494eb5b5915fff982dd884dd002c):

> The w flag is not needed for key=val type options but only forces all
>   options to be that format.

Now [the manpage reads](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/procps/sysctl.8.en.html):

> -w, --write Use this option when all arguments prescribe a key to be set.